# How to update an inner join table with split_string?

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-update

I have one simple table, such as:

Table A:

| Id | Role |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin |
| 2 | Member |
| 3 | Reviewer |
| 4 | Contributor |
| 5 | Champion |
| 6 | Casual |
| 7 | Manager |

I have 2 parameters, one is that
`@Id Nvarchar(max) = '1,2,3'` that will contains values of all the Ids that I need to update.
`@Roles Nvarchar(max)='Member,Casual,Manager'` that will be mapped to the `@Ids` above.
So basically, I want to update Id 1 with value Member, Id 2 with Casual and Id 3 with Manager.

The result should be:

| Id | Role |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Member |
| 2 | Casual |
| 3 | Manager |
| 4 | Contributor |
| 5 | Champion |
| 6 | Casual |
| 7 | Manager |

I was thinking about `split_string` the both `@Ids and @Roles`, find the inner join table, and update in a loop, but I don't know how it is going to implement in the SQL server.

I would love to hear any feedback or a way on how to implement it in the SQL server.

Thank you.

Comment: Read the documentation. As documented and noted below, string_split does not guarantee order which is a requirement for your approach. If you pass a TVP, you don't need any of this and you can simply join. So the better question is why you have "tuples" passed as separate arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you can define `key-value` pair between `@Id` and `@Roles`.

Basically,  [`split_string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't resolve that requirement.

> **Return Types:** Returns a `single-column` table whose rows are the
> substrings. The name of the column is `value`.

So I would suggest you create your own `strSplit` like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[strSplit] ( @string nvarchar( MAX), @splitter CHAR( 1) )
RETURNS @res TABLE ( id INT PRIMARY KEY, rank INT, val nvarchar( MAX) )
AS
BEGIN
     IF SUBSTRING ( @string, len ( @string), 1)<>@splitter
          SET @string= @string+@splitter
     DECLARE @start INT, @word nvarchar(MAX), @charindex INT, @i INT
     SET @i=1
     SET @start=1
     SET @charindex= CHARINDEX( @splitter, @string, @start)
     WHILE (@charindex <> 0)BEGIN
          SET @word= SUBSTRING( @string, @start, @charindex - @start)
          SET @start= @charindex +1
          SET @charindex= CHARINDEX( @splitter, @string, @start)
          INSERT INTO @res  VALUES ( @start, @i, @word)
          SET @i=@i+1
     END
     RETURN
END
```

After that, you can easily get the result `key-value` pair like this.

```
SELECT id.val AS ID, Role.val AS Role
FROM strSplit(@Id, ',') Id
INNER JOIN strSplit(@Roles, ',') Role ON Id.rank = Role.rank
```

The output looks like this

```
ID  Role
1   Member
2   Casual
3   Manager
```

And now, you can join with your `Table A` to update.

```
;WITH cte_TempTable AS (
 SELECT id.val AS ID, Role.val AS Role
 FROM strSplit(@Id, ',') Id
 INNER JOIN strSplit(@Roles, ',') Role ON Id.rank = Role.rank
)
UPDATE t
SET t.Role = c.Role
FROM @TableA t
INNER JOIN cte_TempTable c ON t.ID = c.ID
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=68509624b74664ae41fa70ec5edb92c7)

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen Van Phong. It does help a lot. I'll get back to you if I have any more questions :)

Comment: Just did. Thank you very much :)